# Mypy: a generic that helps a decorator annotate a multiple dispatch

Tags: python, mypy

I want to put my functions on some registry and pick the required function based on some arguments provided (a version of multiple dispatch).

This is the sample code:

```
method_registry = {}


def accepts(cls):
    """ A decorator that registers functions on some registry"""
    def register(func):
        method_registry[cls] = func
        return func

    return register


def handle(obj):
    """ Pick a function that corresponds to the provided object class and run it """
    handler = method_registry[obj.__class__]
    handler(obj)
```

now, how do i plan to use it:

```
class Dog:
    def bark(self):
        print('bark')

class Cat:
    def meow(self):
        print('meow')


@accepts(Dog)
def handle_dog(obj):
    obj.bark()


@accepts(Cat)
def handle_cat(obj):
    obj.meow()


# Here comes multiple dispatch
handle(Dog())
handle(Cat())
```

Now, it all works, but when I try to annotate my functions for mypy, I have to type `Cat` and `Dog` twice:

```
@accepts(Dog)
def handle_dog(obj: Dog) -> None:
    obj.bark()


@accepts(Cat)
def handle_cat(obj: Cat) -> None:
    obj.meow()
```

so, I'm guessing there must be a way to create a generic type that could annotate my `obj`-s for me without duplicating the code.

But I cannot seem to make this work.

My attempt was like this:

```
V = TypeVar('V')

def accepts(cls: Type[V]) -> Callable[[Callable], Callable[[V], None]]:

    def register(func: Callable) -> Callable[[V], None]:
        method_registry[cls] = func
        return func

    return register
```

but this doesn't help:

```
@accepts(Dog)
def handle_dog(obj) -> None:
    reveal_type(obj)  # Revealed type is 'Any'
    obj.bark()
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: AFAIK mypy can't add annotations for you since it's static code analyzer, it should be done manually

Answer (score 0):

The code as it stands mandates you specify the type twice: once for `MyPy` and once for `accept`. These types could, in theory, be different.

If you'd like to have them both use the same value, one of them needs to change.
It'd me much easier for you to change your `accepts` method rather than write a plugin for MyPy. It could use *the same annotation* by inspecting your functions' `__annotations__` field.

```
def accepts():
    def register( func ):
        cls = func.__annotations__["obj"]
        method_registry[cls] = func
        return func
    
    return register

...

@accepts()
def handle_dog( obj: Dog ):
    obj.bark()

@accepts()
def handle_cat( obj: Cat ):
    obj.meow()
```